# What determines whether or not I can see a player's competitive rank in Quick Play?

Tags: overwatch

What determines whether or not I can see a player's competitive rank in Quick Play?

Sometimes when I hover over a player's name in the list I can see their ranks. Other times I cannot.  Am I limited to only seeing players who have already done their 10 placement matches? Am I restricted to only seeing players within a certain rank, because for the most part I have yet to see anyone with a rank sub-2k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only see a rank if a player has completed their 10 placement matches for the current season. Otherwise, it will not show any rank. Occasionally, you may see ranks that say <500; this would appear to be some sort of "anti-embarrassment" feature.

Comment: I believe the reasoning behind the <500 ranking is less to do with anti-embarrassment, and more to do with preventing people trying to deliberately get a rank of 1.